# Flutter - Is the device an Ipad in Landscape?

Tags: ipad, flutter, orientation

I'm attempting to identify in Flutter when the connected device is an iPad and if it is in landscape mode.  So far, I've figured out how to determine the orientation and if it's an iOS device - but not specifically how to target all versions of iPad.

I would settle for being able to identify a tablet from a phone from a computer at this point - but my goal is to be as concise as possible.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_device_type

code snippet

```
//Get the physical device size
print( Device.size );
//Quick methods to access the physical device width and height
print("Device Width: ${Device.width}, Device Height: ${Device.height}");

//To get the actual screen size (Which is same as what MediaQuery gives)
print( Device.screenSize );
//Quick methods to access the screen width and height
print("Device Width: ${Device.screenWidth}, Device Height: ${Device.screenHeight}");

//Check if device is tablet
if( Device.get().isTablet ){
    //do something large
}

//Check if device is iphone x
if( Device.get().isIphoneX ){
    //Do some notch business
}

//Other utility methods
print( Device.get().isPhone );
print( Device.get().isAndroid );
print( Device.get().isIos );

//So to check for iPad for instance
if( Device.get().isIos && Device.get().isTablet ){
    //make the font larger :)
}
```

Comment: I was attempting to figure it out without using another package but I think that's probably the best solution.  Thanks for the help!